# Facebook SDK 3.0.1 Login Problem

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, authentication

My Facebook SDK version was 2.1.2 and i upgraded it to 3.0.1. After my code is not working. I just change Facebook SDK files. I didn't change anything in my code.

Here is error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /home/galeri/domains/****.com/public_html/beta/facetest/src/base_facebook.php on line 970

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downgrading to 3.0.0 and then looking at this issue to solve the problem you will get: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/376

I did the same as you upgrade from 2.x to 3.0.0 and thankfully this was the only issue.

I definitely won't be upgrading to 3.0.1, there are too many issues.

The guy ptarjan has a habit of closing issues without fully investigating them and doesn't always get to the heart of the bugs.  It's working for me and won't upgrade.

Edit: There is even an issue about this, do you check github issues? :

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/296

Answer (score -1):

Were you using Oauth to log in before? Check the docs, they describe the oath process
EDIT:
[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) is a link to the page that shows how to authenticate using Oauth

Comment: No need to look at the page, when the SDK does it all for you.